# EntityFramework Datafirst approach

Tags: entity-framework

My question is simple.but could not fine answer for that.Can we use dbcontext in entity framework datafirst approach?Am learning entityframework concept in asp dotnet web application.I searched in google a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, take a look at this blog :

http://thedatafarm.com/blog/data-access/code-first-entity-framework-4-1-videos-and-articles-on-msdn/

it is very instructive

PS : Maybe next time search on google before asking here

Comment: thank you.Am a beginner."i searched many time but had doubt.did not get answer.so that i posted in stack overflow"